# Why the "show" word also gets printed by the second thread although we have applied the synchronized keyword meaning we have locked the object

Tags: java

Here is my code

```
class Thread1 extends Thread
{
 public synchronized  void show()
 {
  System.out.println("show");
  System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
  try
  {
   Thread.sleep(5000);
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
   System.out.println(e);
  }
 }

 public synchronized void display()
 {
  System.out.println("Display");
  System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
 }

 public static void main(String args[])
 {
  Thread1 z=new Thread1();
  z.set();
 }

 public void set()
 {
  Thread1 tr=new Thread1();
  Thread1 tr1=new Thread1();
  tr.start();
  tr1.start();
 }

 public void run()
 {
  try
  {
   show();
   display();
  }

  catch(Exception e)
  {
   System.out.println(e);
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you meant to ask about why `show` is printed by both threads before either of the thread names are printed.

You are synchronizing your instance methods, so they are implicitly locking on the object on which the method is called.  However, you have 2 different `Thread1` objects locking on themselves, so neither thread is stopping the other from entering the synchronized methods.

If you intend to have only one `Thread` execute each of the `synchronized` methods at a time, then you need to lock on a common object.  Use a `synchronized` block that locks on `Thread1.class`.

Here is what that looks like for the `show` method.

```
public void show()
{
    synchronized (Thread1.class)
    {
        System.out.println("show");
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

The `display` method can be modified similarly.

Answer (score 0):

You are instantiating two different objects that have their own state (tr and tr1). They never access the same synchronised block, and thus never block waiting for the other one to finish.

Try moving the show method to another class, instantiate that class and then pass it to tr and tr1 as a constructor parameter, for example.